# Be Quick and Calculating..Take Four Shots

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

To Target Sum of 100 Exactly .

By shooting the right different numbers in four shots summing upto 100.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

> the last digit of the 4 numbers has to add to something congruent with 10,

only a few combinations can work off the bat. For example,

> 15, 23, 12, 30: 5 + 3 + 2 + 0 = 10

But this one doesn't work. Looking at more that do, I found

> 44 + 23 + 18 + 15 = 100

Which is the answer.

Comment: Got that right..quick and calculating...

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

> [image]
>  a.k.a $44+33+23+0=100$

Comment: You are not on target,!..otherwise they add up